# Python: Installation of MPlayer/MEncoder for Windows

Tags: python

I am trying to install MPlayer for Windows, and using the command line

```
os.system("mencoder...")
```

I want to be able to compile a series of images into a time-lapse video. The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
'C:\Python27\Lib\MPlayer-1.1\mencoder' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So my question is, when extracting the MPlayer-1.1.tar.gz file, where are you supposed to put the folder so that the command line will run properly in Windows?

I downloaded MPlayer from here: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html.

Comment: `MPlayer-1.1.tar.gz` is the source code. You need to get the binaries for Windows from over at http://oss.netfarm.it/mplayer-win32.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you downloaded the source code of MPlayer which you cannot run via command line. You have to compile the whole project perhaps. Otherwise download the binaries just like Dan D said.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, thank you for your help, as well as Dan D.'s help. :)